# How can i add a customized reading pane for my Add-In in Outlook with C# in Vsto?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-form-region

I am in the process of implementing an add-in for outlook. I am currently implementing all messages with the `MessageBox`. As this is not a nice solution, I would like to display the messages via a reading pane or something similar. How can I implement this in Vsto with C#? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task panes would be a good option for displaying any information in a non-modal fashion (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2022).

Note that unlike Outlook form regions, task panes give you full control over when they are shown and hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider creating a form region in Outlook. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022) for more information. Also you may find the [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2022) helpful.

Another option is custom task panes in Outlook. Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Display custom task panes with email messages in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2019) article.